# How Can I extract 'date' part from a timespan in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

I have a list of time-span in a SQL table and other variables in other tables. With join scripts, I am trying to extract two columns: `name` and `time`.

```
name      time 
soo       12/9/2001 13.25
nu        13/4/2005 4.33
```

etc.

with the below scripts I get syntax error. Can anyone help me in this respect?

```
SELECT data1.files.names,
       data1.registrationtime.date(regtime)
FROM data1.files,
     data1.registrationtime
WHERE files.id=fileID
  AND registrationtime.id=regID
```

The syntax error is under the parenthesizes of the `regtime`

Comment: Hi, could you please show us what you have used in the WHERE clause and the table columns.

Comment: Yes sure. I edited the above text

Comment: Have you tried using the following in the WHERE clause: data1.files.id=fileID AND data1.registrationtime.id=regID

Comment: it is not working still I have the syntax error

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you would like to extract the date part from the timestamp in MySQL.

This can be done by using the `DATE_FORMAT()` function. e.g.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data1.registrationtime, '%d/%c/%y') 
FROM ...
```